# Why don't icons appear beside all the tree nodes I expect?

Tags: delphi, icons, virtualtreeview

I'm trying to scan a folder for files & subfolders and then add the result to a VirtualStringTree .. and this works great except when when it comes to add an icon to each node of the treeview (icon are from the system shell icons).

A weird problem occures and icons are shown only with certain nodes & in most cases just one icon is what I get ( See the image below).

[image]

**Here is the code I use:**

The tree node data declaration:

```
nodeData=record
          Text:String;
          ImageIndex:integer;
         end;

PNodeData=^nodeData;
```

& here's the code that scans for files/folders

```
procedure scanDir(const Dir:string);
var SR: TSearchRec;
begin

addNewNode(Dir); 

if(FindFirst(IncludeTrailingBackslash(Dir) + '*.*', faAnyFile or faDirectory, SR)=0)then
 try
  if(isFile)then addNewNode(IncludeTrailingBackslash(Dir)+SR.Name);
  else if(isFolder)then scanDir(IncludeTrailingBackslash(Dir)+SR.Name);  // recursive call!
 until(FindNext(Sr)<>0);
 finally
 FindClose(SR);
 end;
end;
```

the code to add a new node:

```
procedure addNewNode(Text:String);
var theNode,Node:PVirtualNode;
    d:PNodeData;
    parent:string;
    SHFileInfo :TSHFileINfo;
    Icon: TIcon;
begin

parent:=ExtractFileDir(Text);

if(hashmap.ContainsKey(parent))then theNode:=hashmap.Items[parent]
else theNode:=nil;

Icon := TIcon.Create;

SHGetFileInfo(PChar(Text), 0, SHFileInfo,  SizeOf(SHFileInfo),
                SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_SMALLICON );

Icon.Handle := SHFileInfo.hIcon;

// begin updating
Form1.theTree.BeginUpdate;

// add a child node
Node:=Form1.theTree.AddChild(theNode);

d:=Form1.theTree.GetNodeData(Node);

// add a checkbox
Node.CheckType:=ctCheckBox;
Node.CheckState:=csCheckedNormal;

if((ExtractFileExt(Text)='')and(not hashmap.ContainsKey(Text)))
then hashmap.Add(Text, Node);

// assign a text to the newly created node
d^.Text:=ExtractFileName(Text);

// assign an ImageIndex to the newly created node
d^.ImageIndex:=Form1.treeImageList.AddIcon(Icon);

// end update
Form1.theTree.EndUpdate;

// Destroy the Icon
DestroyIcon(SHFileInfo.hIcon);
end;
```

the code of the treeVeiw OnGetImageIndex:

```
procedure TForm1.theTreeGetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex;
  var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: Integer);

var  FileInfo:PNodeData;
begin
  FileInfo := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  ImageIndex := FileInfo^.ImageIndex;
end;
```

PS: **treeImageList** is the imageList linked to The **treeView.images** property

Comment: Have you debugged the program, ie did you check the return value of the `treeImageList.AddIcon(Icon)`? If it returns `-1` then adding the icon failed... also check the imagelist after you have added all the files - does it contain all the expected images?

Comment: You're calling many library functions, and any one of them might fail, but you're ignoring the return values of all of them. Clues to what's wrong are right in front of you, but it's your responsibility to look.

Comment: Much easier than maintaining your own list of icons is using the system image list of Windows. You can get its handle using this code:  


    `SysHandle := SHGetFileInfo(PChar(SystemDrive), 0, FileInfo, sizeof(FileInfo), SHGFI_SMALLICON+SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);`  


Our (JAM Software) ShellBrowser Components for Delphi come with a ready to use TImageList descendant that wraps the system image list.